# Jquery ajax issue with php sessions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

i have a jQuery ajax call with this parameters :

```
    url : "ajax/_method_",
    type : 'POST' ,
    data : _data_,
    dataType : 'JSON',
    async: true,
```

in my ajax controller i make a setAttempt & checkAttempts functions to prevent users from multiple ajax requests
this is my code :

```
public function checkAttempts()
{
    $counter = 0;
    $attempts = Session::get(AJAX);
    $attempts = ($attempts === false) ? [] : $attempts;
    //when user make his first request => there's no ajax requests Session
    if ($attempts === false)
        Session::set(AJAX, []);
    else
        $this->setAttempt();
    foreach ($attempts as $key => $attempt)
    {
        if (time() - intval($attempt) <= 10)
            $counter++;
        else
            Session::destroyArray(AJAX, $key);
    }
    return $counter >= 5;
}

public function setAttempt()
{
    return Session::setArray(AJAX, time());
}
```

this code works fine if i acceed directly to ' ajax/*method*
but when i use the jquery ajax request utility i face a problem which when the user make his first request the session initialized to :

```
   array (size=3)
    'AJAX_ATTEMPTS' => 
     array (size=4)
      0 => int _timestamp_
      1 => int _timestamp_
      2 => int _timestamp_
      3 => int _timestamp2_
```

if found that the method ajax/checkAttempts is called several times when i open  another controller such ( home - store ... ) and this shoudln't happen because the method declared only in the ajax controller and called only in the ajax __constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(false);
    if ($this->checkAttempts())
    {
        exit();
    }
}
```

by using the debug_backtrace() function i found that the application core call the ajax constructor when it initialize the controller class!
how to prevent this issue ?

Comment: I suppose it is because you called ajax/method directly and then tried to call it using ajax, but the Session has already been initialized.

Comment: i clear this sessions after using the directly call ,
but i found something new that the ajax/checkAttempts method called when open any another Controller but that shouldn't be happen because this method is only in the ajax controller !!

Comment: Can you invoke your method only when you recieve ajax call? I think, preventing initializing the controller class is wrong. A class should be initialized properly.

Comment: i call this method only in the ajax class __construct but this __construct of the child is called when i initialize the parent class Controller that's what make this issue !